# Create Running in % from distinct count text values and filter by row

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Im doing a cohort retention rate analysis in POWER BI and Im stuck when trying to do a running %  ....

So far I could create a table which displays like this:

```
          Month 0   Month 1     Month 2   Month 3
Cohort 1    100%     5%          4%         7%
Cohort 2    100%     2%          3%         --
Cohort 3    100%     4%          --
Cohort 4    100%     --
```

As we can see,  each month is showing how many people from each cohort are coming back month by month.

To calculate the % of people who are coming back im doing a DISTINCTCOUNT of emails (text value) and then showing the results as % of row total

What I want to do is a table with the running% like this:

```
         Month 0    Month 1     Month 2   Month 3
Cohort 1    100%     5%          9%         16%
Cohort 2    100%     2%          5%         --
Cohort 3    100%     4%          --
Cohort 4    100%     --
```

Ive tried this measure but is not bringing what i want...

```
      Running % =
          CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT
               (Transactions[Customer Id]);
                   FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Transactions);
                      Transactions[Month]<= MAX(Transactions[Month])))
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help, so far I couldnt find a solution :/

Many Thanks in advance, have a good one!